# Images are not loading in full image view using Glide

Tags: android, android-glide

I am using Glide to load image in image view but images are not loading in full width as image view they are leaving some empty space on both sides.

This is what I have been trying so far

```
RequestOptions options = new RequestOptions();
options.fitCenter(); 
Glide.with(context).load(model.getBannerImage()).apply(options).into(offerImage);
```

[image]

This is what I get after image loaded in image view it shows empty space on both side how can I get this image in full image view someone please let me know any help will be appreciated.

**THANKS**

Comment: Maybe the images you are receiving do not match your image view width? What you can do is to make your image view `wrap_content` OR center crop the image using Glide built-in function `.centerCrop()`.

Comment: @Taseer Ahmad you are right

Comment: Also useful to diagnose this kind of issues (in this case, to confirm that your `ImageView` was the right size and that was a scale problem) Cmd-Shift-A -> Layout Inspector

Comment: @Basi Please don't use the glide tag for questions about the Android image loading library. Use [android-glide] instead. See [How do I avoid misusing tags?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/354427/6296561) and [the tagging guide](/help/tagging).

Answer (score 0):

Use `android:scaleType="centerCrop"` in your ImageView XML code.

Comment: android:scaleType="fitXY" is worked for me thanks for help.

Comment: @Digvijay please accept the answer if it helped you, so others can find the solution as well.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

```
RequestOptions options = new RequestOptions();
options.centerCrop(); 
Glide.with(context).load(model.getBannerImage()).apply(options).into(offerImage);
```

also you can set in xml (ImageView):

```
android:scaleType="centerCrop"
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `centerCrop` in `RequestOptions`

```
RequestOptions options = new RequestOptions();
options.centerCrop();
```

Comment: It didn't worked but adding android:scaleType=fitXY worked for me thanks for help.